# Label encode variable with multiple values

Tags: python, one-hot-encoding, label-encoding

My variable consists of multiple ingredients. Each consists of different ingredients separated by a comma. 
I used One Hot Encoding for multiple values(MultiLabelBinarizer()), but it increased my dimension of the dataset.

Do we have some appropriate method for this situation?

My variable looks like this:

```
df['ingredients_str'].head()

0    romaine lettuce, black olives, grape tomatoes
1    plain flour,ground pepper,salt,tomatoes
2    eggs,pepper,salt,mayonaise,cooking oil
3    water,vegetable oil,wheat,salt
4    black pepper,shallots,cornflour,cayenne
Name: ingredients_str, dtype: object
```

Comment: after splitting ingredients in your series, find count for every ingredient after that you can map ingredients with low count to a new category such as "other". This will help you with high dimensionality

Comment: Take most frequent categories and skip the rest, for more refer this http://proceedings.mlr.press/v7/niculescu09/niculescu09.pdf